# Is really necessary to have a payload built into JWT?

Tags: jwt

Every example code describing JWT usage talks about a payload, usually this is user information like name and role.

I'm wondering what's the point of encoding that information inside the JWT when there's no additional security and only burdens the front-end making it load a library specifically to decode the JWT.

What I'm asking is if there's a reason to make this encoding instead of just sending user data (or whatever payload you need to pass) alongside with the JWT in the answer.

Currently I'm sending: (this is ExpressJs code)

```
const jwt = jwtUtils.buildToken(user);
res.json({ jwt });
```

Where `jwt` contains a payload with user information.

But what if I do instead:

```
const user = userModel.get(userId);
const jwt = jwtUtils.buildToken();
res.json({ jwt, user });
```

This way I don't need to decode JWT to access my user data, I would just save the JWT to be able to send it on each further request after authentication and access user data directly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody forces you to put the whole user information into your token, and it is generally recommended to limit the payload of the token to a minimum.

According to [RFC719 section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1) all claims are marked as OPTIONAL.

But one thing you're missing is that the backend usually needs to identify the user from which the incoming request was sent, e.g. to grant access to only the resources the user is allowed to access or for logging purposes etc. Also a user role is sometimes needed on backend side. Every information which you use on backend side for authorization purposes should be part of the token itself, because the signature ensures that this information was not manipulated.

So in most applications it's enough to limit the payload to just a user id and usually also the expiration timestamp.

E.g.:

```
{
  "exp": "1516239022",
  "id": 1
}
```

Other information, such as the user name, are often only used at the fronend and are often meaningless for the backend.

Comment: Great! So my idea of sending data needed in the front-end on a non-encoded field is ok. I can just save the JWT in the front-end for further requests but  I don't need to decode it on the front-end, as all display information can be sent alongside

Comment: @FLC as long as it has no relvance for security, it should be fine and you don't need to decode the token on the front end.